# Argument of type 'x' is not assignable to parameter of type 'x' in Angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am very new to Angular 7. I am facing errors in below line of code. What is wrong in my code?

```js
var x1 = 10, x2 = 100, x3 = datar.map(function (item) { return [ item.xmax ] })
   .reduce(function(a, b) { return Math.max(a, b); }); //error
var y1 = 10, y2 = 100, y3 = datar.map(function (item) { return [ item.ymax ] })
   .reduce(function(a, b) { return Math.max(a, b); }); //error
```

In above code I get error: Argument of type `number[]` is not assignable to parameter of type `number` **at 'a, b'** in code `return Math.max(a, b)`

```js
var data = [ [0,0,0],[0,1,4],[0,2,1],[0,3,1]
                ,[1,0,0],[1,1,9],[1,2,4],[1,3,1]
                ,[2,0,0],[2,1,9],[2,2,9],[2,3,9]
                ,[3,0,0],[3,1,0],[3,2,0],[3,3,0] ];
     
data = data.map(function (item) { //error
    return [item[1], item[0], item[2] || '-'];
});
```

In above code I get error:
`Type (string | number)[][] is not assignable to type number[][].`
**at 'data'**

```js
var objseries = datar.map(function(x) {
       return {
            type: 'scatter',
            symbol: 'diamond',
            symbolSize: 10,
            itemStyle:{
                normal:{ 
                    color:  x.color
                }
            },
            data: x.data.map(function (item) {
                return [
                item[0] <= x1 ? 0 + ((item[0] - 0) / ((x1 - 0) / 100)) / 100 :
                (item[0] <= x2 ? 1 + ((item[0] - x1) / ((x2 - x1) / 100)) / 100 :
                (item[0] <= x3 ? 2 + ((item[0] - x2) / ((x3 - x2) / 100)) / 100  : 2)),//error
               
                item[1] <= y1 ? 0 + ((item[1] - 0) / ((y1 - 0) / 100)) / 100 :
                (item[1] <= y2 ? 1 + ((item[1] - y1) / ((y2 - y1) / 100)) / 100 :
                (item[1] <= y3 ? 2 + ((item[1] - y2) / ((y3 - y2) / 100)) / 100  : 2)),//error
               
                item[0], item[1]
                ];
            }),
        }
    });
```

In above code I get error:

> Operator '<=' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'number[]' at 'item[0] <= x3' in code `item[0] <= x3 ? 2 + ((item[0] - x2) / ((x3 - x2) / 100)) / 100  : 2))`

and:

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type **at x3** in code '(x3-x2)'

### Edited

I get below error in below piece of code:

```
Type '(string | number)[][]' is not assignable to type 'number[][]'.
  Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
chart.component.ts(77, 13): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ type: string; symbol: string; symbolSize: number; itemStyle: { normal: { color: string; }; }; data: number[][]; }'
```

```js
var datar = [
    {
        name: 'TEST-A',
        data: [
            [4,4],[25,4],[700,4],[4,40],[25,40],[160,40]
        ],
        xmax: 700,
        ymax: 40,
        color: 'purple',
    },
    {
        name: 'TEST-B',
        data: [
            [10.0, 8.04],
            [8.0, 6.95],
            [13.0, 7.58],
            [9.0, 8.81],
        xmax: 160,
        ymax: 400,
        color: 'green',
    }
];

var objseries = datar.map(function(x) {
   return {
        type: 'scatter',
        symbol: 'diamond',
        symbolSize: 10,
        itemStyle:{
            normal:{ 
                color:  x.color
            }
        },
        data: x.data.map(function (item) {
            return [
            item[0] <= x1 ? 0 + ((item[0] - 0) / ((x1 - 0) / 100)) / 100 :
            (item[0] <= x2 ? 1 + ((item[0] - x1) / ((x2 - x1) / 100)) / 100 :
            (item[0] <= x3 ? 2 + ((item[0] - x2) / ((x3 - x2) / 100)) / 100  : 2)),
           
            item[1] <= y1 ? 0 + ((item[1] - 0) / ((y1 - 0) / 100)) / 100 :
            (item[1] <= y2 ? 1 + ((item[1] - y1) / ((y2 - y1) / 100)) / 100 :
            (item[1] <= y3 ? 2 + ((item[1] - y2) / ((y3 - y2) / 100)) / 100  : 2)),
           
            item[0], item[1]
            ];
        }),
    }
}); 
    
objseries.splice(0, 0, {
    name: 'Severe Moderate Mild',
    xAxisIndex : 1,
    yAxisIndex : 1,
    type: 'heatmap',
    data: data, //error here
    label: {
        normal: {
            show: false
        }
    }
});
```

This code will then go and sit in 'series' property of
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=doc-example/scatter-visualMap-categories&edit=1&reset=1
(this link is just for example to explain the relation)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

These errors are all typescript errors. Since you don't have any explicit types on anything, and didn't mention typescript, i wonder if you might not be aware that typescript is being used. In any event, here's what those errors mean:

> Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number' at 'a, b' in code 'return Math.max(a, b)'

This is pointing out that `a` and `b` are arrays, not numbers, so doing Math.max on them is not going to work. The reason they are arrays is because of the previous line where you do this:

```
datar.map(function (item) { return [ item.ymax ] })
```

Did you perhaps mean to `return item.ymax` instead of `return [ item.ymax ]`?

> In above code I get error: Type '(string | number)[][]' is not assignable to type 'number[][]'.

On the `var data =` line, you aren't defining your types, so typescript makes its best guess. Since you provided a 2 dimensional array with every element being a number, typescript infers that the type for `data` is `number[][]`. Then later, when you try to stick a string into it, it's pointing out that strings are not part of the type. If you want strings to be an option, you'll need to specify the type yourself, as in:

```
var data: (string | number)[][] = [
  [0,0,0],[0,1,4],[0,2,1],[0,3,1],
  [1,0,0],[1,1,9],[1,2,4],[1,3,1],
  [2,0,0],[2,1,9],[2,2,9],[2,3,9],
  [3,0,0],[3,1,0],[3,2,0],[3,3,0]
];
```

> Operator '<=' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'number[]' at 'item[0] <= x3' in code 'item[0] <= x3 ? 2 + ((item[0] - x2) / ((x3 - x2) / 100)) / 100 : 2))'

x3 is an array, so trying to check if something is `<=` to it is nonsensical. My guess is this issue should go away when you fix the first issue where you were creating arrays instead of individual numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Nicholas

Comment: As before, the problem is that you're letting typescript guess at the types. You didn't say what the types are on this objseries array, so the best it can guess is that the data property is of type `number[][]`. Then later on, when you try to splice in data that might have strings in it, typescript points out that this doesn't match. Add explicit types when you define objseries so that typescript doesn't need to guess.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I changed the code from **var data: (string | number)[][] = [ [0,0,0],[0,1,4],[0,2,1],[0,3,1]....so on** to **var data: number[][] = [ [0,0,0],[0,1,4],[0,2,1],[0,3,1]...so on** but now I get another error at the mentioned (EDITED) part, which is below:

Comment: New Error(in continuation to above comment):

Argument of type '{ name: string; xAxisIndex: string; yAxisIndex: string; type: string; data: number[][]; label: { normal: { show: boolean; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ type: string; symbol: string; symbolSize: number; itemStyle: { normal: { color: string; }; }; data: number[][]; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type '{ type: string; symbol: string; symbolSize: number; itemStyle: { normal: { color: string; }; }; data: number[][]; }'

Comment: These issues are going to keep coming up so long as typescript is force to guess what you mean. Inevitably, it will guess wrong some of the time. If you want to use typescript in your project, then i recommend thinking through your types and writing explicit interfaces for them. If you want these objects to sometimes have a name and sometimes not, then you can make the name property optional in their interface.